# force latexdiff to ignore small changes and only consider the blocks larger than a size

Tags: latexdiff

I am using `latexdiff` to highlight the changes between two tex files.
It can find and highlight the added/deleted parts.

But I want it to only show the large blocks of texts, and not the minor changes: for instance I want to force it to only consider the blocks of token whose size is larger than 10 words.

First, it seemed that `MINWORDSBLOCK` parameter is supposed to do that. But even after setting it to a different value, it still shows the short changes (one-word blocks).

Is there any alternative way to do that?

This is the part of command that I use in my batch file:

```
latexdiff --exclude-textcmd="cite,equation,align,figure,label" 
--preamble=diffpreamble.tex --config MINWORDSBLOCK=10 --flatten old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

Comment: For this special use case, it might be easiest to just go with manual markup I think. You can still use latexdiff's`\DIFadd` and `\DIFdel` but just use the preamble from latexdiff (`latexdiff --show-preamble`) and never actually run latexdiff on the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature of latexdiff that would allow to do that. The MINWORDSBLOCK configuration variable has a different purpose, i.e. it is there to avoid that a larger change (say a replacement of a whole paragraph) gets subdivided into lots of smaller changes, which technically are a more minimal changeset and thus preferred by the diff algorithm but which make the diff file hard to read.

Comment: If you wish you can submit this as a feature request on the latexdiff github site (but will probably not be treated with priority unless supported by several other people - I think this sounds like a pretty niche requirement)